# ERROR: snapshot_root must be a full path

Tags: rsnapshot

I want to use rsnapshot to make backups of some folders on a remote server.

I've already setup Key Based Authentication, and I've specified in rsnapshot.conf:

```
snapshot_root user@server.com/
```

however I get the following error:

> ERROR: snapshot_root snapshot_root
>   user@server.com/ - snapshot_root \
>            must be a full path

So I was wondering if the only way is to mount first the remote server and how (I'm on Ubuntu 9.04)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the way that rsnapshot works. Rsnapshot runs on a server system onto which you backup the files from a remote system - it pulls files into the snapshot_root to store them. If you have `snapshot_root` set to `/backups/` then

```
backup /home/ localhost/
```

will backup the local `/home` directory and it's contents to

`/backups/<interval>.<n>/localhost/home`

and

```
backup root@remote.tld:/var/www/ remote.tld
```

will backup the `/var/www/` directory from `remote.tld` using rsync over ssh to

`/backups/<interval>.<n>/remote.tld/var/www`

EDIT:

You can run rsnapshot as any user. You will need to copy the `/etc/rsnapshot.conf` file to somewhere that you can edit it eg ~/rsnapshot/ . You will need to change the `lockfile` directive as you most likely wont be able to write to write to it's default as a standard user.

```
lockfile        /home/patrick/rsnapshot/rsnapshot.pid
```

You then invoke rsnapshot thus

```
rsnapshot -c /home/patrick/rsnapshot/rsnapshot.conf hourly
```

Do you have access to cron as a standard user on the server ?

Comment: nmhmm... ok. So rsnapshot should be installed on the backup server and not the production server! That's my mistake I guess

Comment: I've actually just realized that I don't have sudo privilegies on the backup server. Does this mean I cannot use rsnapshot for remote backups ?

Comment: @Patrick: See my edit for how to use rsnapshot as any user